# SUMPRODUCT with condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 columns B="Points" and C="Grade"
And i'm trying to find the formula to sum the products of all points*grade for grades >= 60.

I tried this formula with many others, with no success:

```
SUMPRODUCT((B2:B100)*(C2:C100)*(C2:C100=">60"))
```

**Output** is: 0

Anyone has suggestions ?

Comment: My suggestion is to create a new column and put this formula `=IF(C2>=60;C2*B2;0)` in it, make this for all rows and in the end sum it all.

Comment: @Math i did it for the first place, because i know there is a better with no column usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B100,C2:C100,--(C2:C100>=60))
```

Comment: @Orel: I think you should mark his answer for your question.

Comment: @PhucNguyen, Yup. Marked + Up voted.