# Conditional SUMPRODUCT in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very long list with three colums:

```
| Country     | Value | Percent |SUMPRODUCT for country    |
|-------------|-------|---------|--------------------------|
| Netherlands | 5     | 0.3     |            ?             |
| Belgium     | 4     | 0.1     |            ?             |
| Netherlands | 2     | 0.2     |            ?             |
| Germany     | 6     | 0.9     |            ?             |
| Netherlands | 8     | 0.5     |            ?             |
```

How can I calculate the SUMPRODUCT of column B and C for each country (if A = e.g. The Netherlands).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUMPRODUCT with condition](https://superuser.com/questions/600522/sumproduct-with-condition)

Comment: Thank you for yours response. That does not solve my question as the array is fixed. However, I want my array to be 'dynamic' ... and apply sum product for those cells which are assigned to a specific country

Comment: Can you share some sample data (preferably in an editable format, e.g. you can format it here https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to help us understanding your issue then?

Comment: so do you want to have the sumproduct for the whole country in all of your rows?

Comment: alternatively you can add a helper column to calculat value * percent, then use a pivot table to sum them by country

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Sumproduct to appear only once for each country, fill this formula down from D2:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$12)*(C$2:C$12)*(A$2:A$12=A2)),"")`

This will put the sumproduct next to the first occurrence of the country name.

[image]

If you want the sumproduct to show for *every* country name, just use:

`=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$12)*(C$2:C$12)*(A$2:A$12=A2))`

Answer (score 0):

Now that your question has been edited to show sample data, I suggest this method.  This formula, filled down from cell G2 creates a unique list of the countries:

```
G2 =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$A$2:$A$6)=0),$A$2:$A$6),"")
```

Now this formula, filled down from cell H2 will return the SUMPRODUCTs for each country:

```
H2 =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6)*($C$2:$C$6)*($A$2:$A$6=G2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! What if I don't want to create a drop down list? Because I have ~130 countries and more than 70,000 rows.

Comment: Your recently updated sample data has different story. Seems you want to calculate row by row. But in column A country name are in duplicate. So, in this situation if you want SUMPRODUCT then the above written formula will take care. I've suggested to create Drop Down because it will help you to process faster instead of replace country name again and again in cell D2.

Comment: My formula will use all the values in both columns B and C to calculate SUMPRODUCT for the Country in D2 and produce one value for the said country. In this way you can change country name and get answer. Using D2 is dynamic approach as you have written in comments above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't get it working. I also don't get the last part with $D$2 ... how can D2 be fixed if the SUMPRODUCT is to be calculated for each row according to what country is specified in row A,.

Comment: @Jonas,, read my updated answer carefully, I've described step by step  how to execute the job with alternate options. And also suggest DON't GO ROW by ROW, since it  mess with the Data and SUMPRODUCT will not work.